# Rollback with CFTransaction, CFThrow and CFDump abort

Tags: coldfusion, rollback

I have read the documentation about [cftransaction](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-t/cftransaction.html) but can't figure out the difference between rolling back with `<cfdump var="#myVar#" abort>`, `<cftransaction action="rollback" />` or `<cfthrow message="Error">`

Assume that `var a` is preset for example purposes. All queries inside the `cftransaction` tag only do a rollback when using `cfdump abort`. With the proper `rollback action` or a `cfthrow` tag they do *not* rollback.

I'm new with CF2016. Can someone explain to me the differences between a rollback with one or another?

```
<cftransaction action="begin">
  ...somecode with querys...
  <cfif a eq 1>
    <cftransaction action="rollback" />
  <cfelseif a eq 2>
    <cfthrow message="Error">
  <cfelse>
    <cfdump var="Error" abort>
  </cfif>
</cftransaction>
```

Comment: 1. Please post an example of the actual queries, or a scaled down version that fails to rollback. 2. How are you determining the rollback failed? 3. Why would you use `cfthrow` or `cfdump` to rollback a query? While they might work in some situations, those aren't specifically designed to trigger a rollback like `<cftransaction...>`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use `cfdump` or `cfthrow` to simply rollback a transaction. `cfdump` has pretty much always been notoriously resource hungry. And several years ago, Ben Nadel found that `cfthrow` had a pretty significant performance cost, as well (https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1652-the-performance-cost-of-throwing-exceptions-in-coldfusion.htm). I'd stick with the `cftransaction`, as that's kinda explicitly its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a save-point before doing the rollback action... I'm not 100% sure if you need to explicitly set that before actually being able to do the rollback

Because `<cfabort>` stops processing of the page all the queries that were made in the `<cftransaction>` tag would be reversed,regardless of save points  while with the   `<cftransaction action="rollback" />` you can reset it to a specific point in the set of queries.

For example think about the following flow

```
<cftransaction> 
 <Query 1 > 
 <Query 2 > 
 <cftransaction action = "setsavepoint" savepoint = "#point#"/> 
  <Query 3 > 
 </cftransaction>
```

If query 3 fails with  `<cftransaction action="rollback" savepoint="#point#" />` you can roll back to a point where you wouldnt have to redo the `<Query 1 > <Query 2 >`  and just worry about `<Query 3 >` saving you some overhead by not repeating those queries.  With CFABORT in the CFDUMP it would abort the entire transaction

The last example on this page with the withdraws shows the use of savepoints
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-t/cftransaction.html

Comment: *all the queries that were made in the `<cftransaction>` tag would be reversed,* @GiancarloBenítez - Important caveat. All of that goes out the window if either the CF code or the SQL contains a `commit`. A savepoint != commit. There's no reversing a commit.

Comment: Technically, you _can_ reverse a COMMIT. It's called a RESTORE. :-)

Comment: @Ageax thanks for your comment, indeed I were invoking a method that invoke another one with a commit inside itself, I tried using savepoints...

Comment: ... as @Hedge7707 suggested. So I wasn't able to use the savepoint set before the first commit.

Comment: ... Finally, @Shwan, are you refering to a DB restore or is there any function/method in CF? Thank you all guys!

Comment: @Shawn - Heh, true. I meant *without* "extraordinary" measures ;-) GiancarloBenítez - No, there's nothing built into CF. It requires database commands.

Comment: @GiancarloBenítez Sorry, that was my sad attempt at sarcasm. Nothing in CF to restore, and to be honest, if I was at the point of needing to do a RESTORE, I'd do it on the database. While crying and/or cursing, depending on if it was my fault.